# Get the values from the <xd:doc/>

Tags: version, filenames, xslt-3.0, oxygenxml

I want to access the version information which I store in the

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
<xd:doc scope="stylesheet">
<xd:ul>
    <xd:li>
            <xd:i>Updates</xd:i>: <xd:ul>
                            <xd:li>20.11.2018, version: <xd:i>1.1.0</xd:i></xd:li>
                            <xd:li>08.03.2019, version: <xd:i>2.0.0</xd:i></xd:li>
                            <xd:li>11.03.2019, version: <xd:i>2.0.1</xd:i></xd:li>
            </xd:ul>
    </xd:li>
</xd:ul>
</xd:doc>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Normally the XPath of the `@select` is evaluated to the xml-file which is currently transforming. But how refer XPath to the (main) XSL-stylesheet?

Another option would be to use `fn:doc()`. But I want to place the version-writing-functionality in an external module, so there will be dynamic file names and I don't know how to get the xsl-file name

I use oXygen XML editor 20.1 where I define the transformation scenarios.

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the problem. Where do you have those elements, inside the XSLT stylesheet? Where exactly? With XSLT 2/3 it would be best to put them into a variable or parameter, then use e.g. `$var-name/xd:li[xd:i = 'Updates']/xd:ul/xd:li`. If you have them as top level elements and want to access them, to access the stylesheet use `document('')` e.g. `document('')/*/xd:li[xd:i = 'Updates']/xd:ul/xd:li`.

Comment: In my view it is easier to simply use a variable or parameter directly e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet ...><xsl:param name="documentation"><xd:doc ...>...</xd:doc></xsl:param>`, then you can use `$documentation//xd:li[xd:i = 'Updates']/xd:ul/xd:li[last()]/xd:i/string()`. But I guess you are using some data elements to include some documentation in the XSLT and the approach you have used is necessary as some other tools like a documentation generator expects the top level `xd:doc` element.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I generate documentation with a build-in template by oXygen. But it's good to know another approach.

Answer (score 0):

@MartinHonnen Thank you. I updated the code in the question. As you may see I store the version in the docs of the stylesheet.

The `document('') / doc('')` was what I needed. So I implemented the following:

I put the document-node of the main stylesheet in the variable which is placed in this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentStylesheet" select="doc('')"/>
```

then refer to it in the external module

```
 <xsl:variable as="xs:string" name="versionXSLT" select="$currentStylesheet//xd:li[xd:i = 'Updates']/xd:ul/xd:li[last()]/xd:i/string()"/>
```

I also use it to get the name of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:variable as="xs:string" name="currentStylesheetName" select="tokenize(document-uri($currentStylesheet), '/')[last()]"/>
```

Are there maybe better solutions?